# tensorflow mnist tutorial

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, tensorflow

i have a question about the tutorial of tensorflow to train the mnist database
how do i create my own batch without using next_batch() , the idea is to train with a batch of 50 ,then 100 and so but it has to be in order

here is the code

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y_conv), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
for i in range(20000):
    batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)#revisar aqui
    if i%100 == 0:
        train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
        print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuracy))
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})
```

Answer (score 1):

### In a nutshell

If you have a look at what `mnist.train` is you'll find there are two numpy arrays in it:
`mnist.train.images` (shape `(55000, 784)`)and `mnist.train.labels` (shape `(55000, 10)`).Then all you have to do is iterate on these.

### Example

This example is voluntarily a bit complicated so that it is robust to whatever sizes you chose but keeps the idea of fixing a number of batches as primary information on how much you want to train on the dataset :

```
X_train = mnist.train.images
Y_train = mnist.train.labels
number_of_examples = X_train.shape[0]
batch_size = 1000
number_of_batches = 200
epoch = 0

for i in range(number_of_batches):
    

    j = (i - epoch) * batch_size % number_of_examples
    k = (i - epoch + 1) * batch_size % number_of_examples

    if (k < j):
        k = number_of_examples
        batch_x = X_train[j:number_of_examples, :]
        batch_y = Y_train[j:number_of_examples, :]

        print('Shuffling data to retrain on dataset')
        data = numpy.concatenate((X_train, Y_train), axis=1)
        np.random.shuffle(data)

        # redefine X_train and Y_train from shuffled dataset
        X_train = data[:, :784]
        Y_train = data[:, 784:794]

        epoch = i + 1
    else:
        batch_x = X_train[j:k, :]
        batch_y = Y_train[j:k, :]

    # [...]
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch_x, y_: batch_y, keep_prob: 0.5})
```

`j` is the row of the dataset which will be the batch's first row
`k` is the last one, so `j-k=batch_size` examples per batch, as expected.
Except if you've reached the end of the dataset (`k<j`)
in which case you just go to its end and then shuffle the
dataset so that batches won't be the same.

You count `i - epoch` and not just `i` so that you're sure you'll always
start at the 1st row of the dataset even when you've already gone
completely through it.
For instance if `number_of_examples = 55555`, `batch_size = 1000` and
`number_of_batches = 200`:  `i = 56` is the first time you go again
through the (shuffled) dataset but `56 * 1000 % 55555 = 445` so you'd
start at row 445 and not 0.

Also you HAVE to concatenate, otherwise the pairs (example, label) will be lost.

---

#### i, j ,k % Whaaat?

Run the toy code below to see how the iteration index behaves:

```
number_of_examples = 55555
batch_size = 1000
number_of_batches = 200
epoch = 0

for i in range(number_of_batches):

    j = (i - epoch) * batch_size % number_of_examples
    k = (i - epoch + 1) * batch_size % number_of_examples

    if (k < j):
        print('Overlap : ', j, number_of_examples)
        epoch = i + 1
    else:
        print(i, '   ', j, k)
```